# Pure mobx (without MST) store models for a real project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobx

Am a react and react Native developer. I am new to mobx and I couldn't find an decent answer to this basic challenge.

How can I arrange my store or stores and their data in a way that is simple. ( don't want to use MST)

The app includes API calls, authentication, form validation and all the real world app functionalities and features.

Hope you get my question.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately your post is soliciting for opinions on application architecture... this site is not a good forum for questions like that. StackOverflow is far better at helping you debug specific technical questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very broad, so I would suggest reading the [docs](https://mobx.js.org/intro/overview.html) if you haven't done so already. Also, even if you don't want to use mobx-state-tree, I highly recommend you use [mobx-react](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react).

Ultimately, you can use mobx to manage react component state in the following ways:

1. Stateful React component with "internal" state managed by mobx

   - No separate store, all state is defined as an `observable` inside the component class
2. Stateful React component with "external" state managed by mobx store

   - All state is managed by an external mobx store that is either instantiated within the component class, passed down as a prop directly from the parent, or injected by a provider
3. Hybrid of the above